# Copy VSS structure to server with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, api, visual-sourcesafe

i want to copy the structure (with the documents) from our vss server to an webserver.
Therefore i want to create an application which is on this webserver.
i want to use asp.net.

i don't know what exactly i need therefore :>

I have to build somekind of connection?
then go throw the structure and copy it somehow :> ?

important: i want to copy the documents with the right creation date ( it changes when i just copy the doc.)

are there APIs for asp.net <-> vss?

Comment: Visual SourceSafe? You want to create a website that interfaces with your source control...?

Comment: i want to create an application, that copies my documents from vss to an folder thats on an other server.

i never worked with vss, i need copies from the documents and there folder-structure.
i dont know what a interface with source control would be :>

Comment: i need to have the copies of the docuemnts ( in there original folder-strucure) in order to work with lucene.net.

Vss --- copy documents --> server

Comment: Is that a "yes" or a "no" to my question?

Comment: if i got it right a "no"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i solved the problem, i copy the documents into an folder, and then i index them with lucene.net